# how dockerfile change centos7 default python version

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a centos7 docker images. It contains yum and anaconda.The python version is 3.6.5 in anaconda. Now I edit a dockerfile.

```
FROM myimage
CMD ["python","--version"]
```

execute `docker build -t xxx . && docker run --name xxx xxx`

It says Python 2.7.5

But if I execute `docker build -t xxx . && docker run -it --name xxx xxx /bin/bash`

And execute python in the container, It says Python3.6.5

There is just python python2 python2.7 in /usr/bin. I execute which python in the container,It says /root/anaconda3/bin/python.

If I use

```
FROM myimage
COPY mydir /mydir
WORKDIR /mydir
RUN echo -e 'from util import Myfunction \nMyfunction()'>>main.py
CMD ["/root/anaconda3/bin/python","main.py"]
```

There is another error:Import Error: libgdal.so.20 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. But if I just execute python main.py in the container ,it works well.

I wonder why the python version is 3.6.5 when execute python in the container,the python version is 2.7.5 when execute by the container packaged image dockerfile. And if I use absolute python path,it report another error

Comment: Could you use `python3 --version`?

Comment: Fyi, most linux distros will default `python` to `python2.7`, since Python is used by the system. It's why a lot of linux tutorials tell you explicitly not to symlink `python3` to `python`

Comment: Which centos7 Docker image are you using? Without more information, all we can tell you is to inspect the image yourself (which should not be hard as such; run `type -all python` in the Bash shell to find out where it's finding `python`).

Comment: how about `/usr/bin/python3 --version`?

Comment: Then that's the one you want to run from your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: There is another error. I wonder why did't the $PATH work. Use the absolute python path caused another error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python image as your base image, example:

```
FROM python:3.6.5
# ...add gdal etc
CMD ["python","--version"]
```

`docker build mypython .`

`docker run --rm -t mypython`

$ Python 3.6.5

The image `python:3.6.5` already come with gcc.

Comment: For some reason,I need to use centos7. Install gdal need gcc ...

Comment: The official python image already come with gcc.

Comment: I need `gcc make subversion gcc-c++ sqlite-devel libxml2-devel python-devel numpy swig expat-devel libcurl-devel` to compile gdal. And I need to execute `sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo sudo make install`. Can the python image do these all?

Comment: Why not? The official image come with build-essential package, anything more you install yourself. This process is the same when you use centos image. You don't need `sudo` to make with this image. Use of official image give you leap start, you are of course free to build your own centos image.

Comment: thanks,I use the python image before ,but there's no yum... I will try it later. But now I want to use the dockerfile to run my code.

Comment: The official python image is debian base, use [apt](https://itsfoss.com/apt-command-guide/). You can try [python-36-centos7](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/python-36-centos7).